# Automated Eth deposits onto L2 (e.g. Arbitrum, Optimism, Polygon/Matic etc.)

Tags: solidity, transfer, polygon, scalability, arbitrum

I would like to build a bridge between L1 and L2 that will send Eth from the smart contract on L1 to the smart contract on L2 automatically. So one will be able to deposit Eth on a smart-contract placed on the Ethereum blockchain. This contract should also have a function that, when called, will automatically send all the deposited Eth to the L1-L2 bridge/gateway, and from there it will go to the smart contract located on L2. Can anyone tell me how to do this? All L2 projects have their websites where you can use the Ethereum-L2 bridge/gateway and manually move the funds, but I haven't found anywhere instructions on how to do this by calling a smart-contract function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific as “native” bridges are chain-related, but you can use more general solution like Synapse or Anyswap, perhaps easier if you plan to deploy on multiple chains.

As for the official bridges :

- Arbitrum: you’ll find the erc20 bridge smart contracts/tutorial here : https://developer.offchainlabs.com/docs/bridging_assets
- Optimism: see here, iirc, you need to first submit your token as a PR https://optimismpbc.medium.com/arbitrary-token-bridging-d552f6bef694
- Polygon: They should release their bridge to third party soon, as they are currently working with whitelisted projects